# How to bond two laminates (same material) separated by distance using compressive pressure in LAMMPS?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, lammps, stress-strain

I would like to simulate the bonding process using compressive pressure for two layers of the same material. Applying a uniaxial strain and using the deform tag in LAMMPS requires PBC in all directions. I am trying to fix the box and apply a load along the z-direction. How do I get this in LAMMPS?